# What this 1 stands for in following code?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def up_low(s):      
    u = sum(1 for i in s if i.isupper())
    l = sum(1 for i in s if i.islower())
    print(s)     
    print( "No. of Upper case characters : %s, \nNo. of Lower case characters : %s" % (u,l))
```

Comment: It doesn't stand for anything, it's just the number `1`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you *do* understand about this code? ``1`` literally stands for the number 1 here. Do you know what this code is intended to do? Can you infer it from the output?

Comment: This is an often-used coding pattern to allow counting the number of times the if condition is True.  We get a 1 each time the condition is True, add these up (sum) to get a total count.

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at one of the lines and explain each path of it.

```
u = sum(1 for i in s if i.isupper())
```

`sum()` - A function that sums the values in a given list
inside the sum there is a generator expression ([PEP-289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)).

The generator expression is:
`1 for i in s if i.isupper()`

what it actually does is:

```
for each value in s: # which means, iterate over the characters
     if value is uppercase character:
          add an integer with the value 1 to the list
```

which means - count the number of uppercase characters in the given string.

Lets use it in an example:

```
s = "HeLlo WoRLD" # We have 6 uppercase characters here.
upper_case_count_list = [1 for i in s if i.isupper()] # Evaluates to: [1,1,1,1,1,1] - A 1 for every uppercase character in s.
sum(upper_case_count_list) # Sums the numbers in our list, which will sum up to 6
```

Comment: Note that there is not a single list nor list comprehension in the code.